# Docker build rocker/r-ver:3.4.4 fail

Tags: r, docker, debian, apt-get

I've been struggling to build

```
FROM rocker/r-ver:3.4.4
MAINTAINER Dennis Leão
RUN apt-get -y update && \
 apt-get install -y build-essential curl openssl
```

But I'm receiving the following error

```
Err:1 http://security-cdn.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates InRelease
  Could not connect to security-cdn.debian.org:80 (151.101.252.204). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Err:2 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease
  Could not connect to cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org:80 (151.101.252.204). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Err:3 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease
  Unable to connect to cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org:http:
Reading package lists...
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/InRelease  Could not connect to cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org:80 (151.101.252.204). - connect (111: Connection refused)
W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/stretch/updates/InRelease  Could not connect to security-cdn.debian.org:80 (151.101.252.204). - connect (111: Connection refused)
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch-updates/InRelease  Unable to connect to cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org:http:
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package build-essential
E: Unable to locate package curl
```

I'm using Macos Mojave, but I was able to build on ubuntu 16. What can I do?

Comment: This result from a search on "xquartz docker.com macos" might have some ideas to try: https://fredrikaverpil.github.io/2016/07/31/docker-for-mac-and-gui-applications/ . If successful, you might write up the results as an answer and if not then you might add the results to your question.

Comment: You have network issues: `https://twitter.com/nprmusic/status/1108782830253801474` and `Could not connect to cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org:80 (151.101.252.204)`.

Comment: But this only occurs on that Dockerfile, I have other images using ubuntu:16 that worked fine on my mac. This is the only one that give me those errors event though it works on ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in the end, it was a DNS problem, changing the DNS of my Mac solved that problem.